# Vala + Gtk doesn't work in mac os x

Tags: macos, compilation, gtk, vala

I installed Vala via homebrew and compiled a normal hello world app in osx 10.9.3. This is the error-message report:

ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libgtk-3.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libgtk-3.dylib

ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libgio-2.0.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libgio-2.0.dylib

ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libatk-1.0.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libatk-1.0.dylib

ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libgdk-3.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libgdk-3.dylib

ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.dylib

ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libcairo-gobject.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libcairo-gobject.dylib

ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.dylib

ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libcairo.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libcairo.dylib

ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.dylib

ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libpango-1.0.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libpango-1.0.dylib

ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libgobject-2.0.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libgobject-2.0.dylib

ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libglib-2.0.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libglib-2.0.dylib

ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libintl.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libintl.dylib

ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libfreetype.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libfreetype.dylib

ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libfontconfig.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/lib/libfontconfig.dylib

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_g_atomic_int_dec_and_test", referenced from:
      _block1_data_unref in helloworld-0067aa.o
  "_g_atomic_int_inc", referenced from:
      _block1_data_ref in helloworld-0067aa.o
  "_g_object_ref_sink", referenced from:
      __vala_main in helloworld-0067aa.o
  "_g_object_unref", referenced from:
      __vala_main in helloworld-0067aa.o
      _block1_data_unref in helloworld-0067aa.o
  "_g_signal_connect_data", referenced from:
      __vala_main in helloworld-0067aa.o
  "_g_slice_alloc0", referenced from:
      __vala_main in helloworld-0067aa.o
  "_g_slice_free1", referenced from:
      _block1_data_unref in helloworld-0067aa.o
  "_g_type_init", referenced from:
      _main in helloworld-0067aa.o
  "_gtk_button_new_with_label", referenced from:
      __vala_main in helloworld-0067aa.o
  "_gtk_button_set_label", referenced from:
      ___lambda3_ in helloworld-0067aa.o
  "_gtk_container_add", referenced from:
      __vala_main in helloworld-0067aa.o
  "_gtk_container_set_border_width", referenced from:
      __vala_main in helloworld-0067aa.o
  "_gtk_init", referenced from:
      __vala_main in helloworld-0067aa.o
  "_gtk_main", referenced from:
      __vala_main in helloworld-0067aa.o
  "_gtk_main_quit", referenced from:
      __gtk_main_quit_gtk_widget_destroy in helloworld-0067aa.o
  "_gtk_widget_set_sensitive", referenced from:
      ___lambda3_ in helloworld-0067aa.o
  "_gtk_widget_show_all", referenced from:
      __vala_main in helloworld-0067aa.o
  "_gtk_window_new", referenced from:
      __vala_main in helloworld-0067aa.o
  "_gtk_window_set_default_size", referenced from:
      __vala_main in helloworld-0067aa.o
  "_gtk_window_set_position", referenced from:
      __vala_main in helloworld-0067aa.o
  "_gtk_window_set_title", referenced from:
      __vala_main in helloworld-0067aa.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: cc exited with status 256
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
[Finished in 2.6s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 /Users/romanfischer/Documents/Vala/gstreamer/src/helloworld.vala -o app.vala && ./app.vala]
[dir: /Users/romanfischer/Documents/Vala/gstreamer/src]
[path: /bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/libexec:/Library/Frameworks/Gtk3.framework/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Vala.framework/bin]

**How to get Gtk Framework to work?
Any help highly appreciated.**

Answer (score 3):

The Gtk+ libaries you have downloaded are compiled for 32-bit processors, but you are attempting to compile for 64-bit. You can:

1. Pass `-X -m32` to build 32-bit binaries.
2. Get 64-bit binaries of Gtk+. This is probably the better choice.

Comment: doesn't work for me. doing 1. ends up with 'unknon target CPU 'i386'

Comment: I don't even know where to find the available option parameters for -X. regarding option2: don't know where to find 64 bit Gtk+ for vala for mac or how to replace it in the vapi

Comment: Sorry, it should be `-m32`. Corrected.

I'm not sure where you got those binaries from as there are no official Gtk+ binaries for OS X. You don't need to replace the VAPI. VAPIs are source level.